# Powershell: how can I check whether there is any conflicts occurred during the svn update

Tags: svn, powershell

I use powershell script to do the svn update, and question is how do I check if there is any conflicts occurred during the process. And how to summary the conflicts?

```
#start svn update
$svn_process =   (Start-Process  -LoadUserProfile -PassThru -FilePath C:\cygwin64\bin\svn.exe -WorkingDirectory $myfolder -ArgumentList @(
'update','--username','alex','--password','pwdxxx', '--force','--accept','tf'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a job,

```
start-job -name MyJob -scriptblock {$svn_process =   (Start-Process  -LoadUserProfile -PassThru -FilePath C:\cygwin64\bin\svn.exe -WorkingDirectory $myfolder -ArgumentList @('update','--username','alex','--password','pwdxxx', '--force','--accept','tf'))}
```

Then grep the results to determine if an error occurred.

```
Receive-Job -Name MyJob -Keep
```

Maybe assign it to a variable so you can regex easier.

```
$a = Receive-Job -Name MyJob -Keep
if ($a -match 'Error'){write-host "It failed, run loop until it doesn't"}
```

Comment: It's a very good idea to start a job, I have tested it and it worked fine. But in my case, the following process has to wait unit the update process finish.

Comment: $svn_process =   (Start-Process  -LoadUserProfile -PassThru -FilePath C:\cygwin64\bin\svn.exe -WorkingDirectory $myfolder -ArgumentList @(
'update','--username','alex','--password','pwdxxx', '--force','--accept','tf'))

Wait-Process -InputObject $svn_process

Comment: As an alternative approach, could I redirect the update process to a file and then parse the file?

Comment: $svn_process =   (Start-Process  -LoadUserProfile -PassThru -FilePath C:\cygwin64\bin\svn.exe -WorkingDirectory $myfolder -ArgumentList @(
'update','--username','alex','--password','pwdxxx', '--force','--accept','tf')) | Outfile XXX.log;

Wait-Process -InputObject $svn_process

#Parse the log

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to mention the job will run asynchronously and you need to add some logic to wait for it to complete first.  Have a read here  http://www.howtogeek.com/138856/geek-school-learn-how-to-use-jobs-in-powershell/

Comment: Thanks a ton Knuckle.
I finally use -RedirectStandardError and -RedirectStandardOutput in Start-Process command to redirect the output. 
This solve my problem. 
Thanks very much for your help.
Anyway, I am going to mark your reply as accepted answer. 

Chuck